# System.Web.WebPages - Not in Add Reference dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to add a reference to System.Web.WebPages
However, it's not in my "add reference" dialog.

I'm already using MVC 3, and Razor views...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are targeting the full `.NET Framework 4` in your project properties and not the `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`. As far as the assembly you are interested in, you will find it in the following folder (remark: this is for a x64 bit OS, for a x86 there is a single Program Files folder):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll
```

So you can simply go ahead and reference it from there.

Answer (score 8):

When you click add reference, check under Assemblies->Extensions.  I found both v1.0 and v2.0 there.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Better than referencing a DLL on your hard disk directly.